# How to restrict standard users from accessing system setting in ubuntu-12.04 desktop?

Tags: permissions, users, system, system-settings, restricted-access

I need to restrict/prevent standard users from accessing "system settings" in UI 
?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really restrict that since there are user specific settings in "System Settings" - If you are scared of someone changing something, as long as they are a standard user they can't change any system-wide settings. If you really wanted to remove their access to "System Settings", you could move the executable to somewhere not in $PATH, and set your $PATH to match the new directory.

Comment: Can you tell me atleast on how to disable "Appearance","Network" and User "Accounts" in System Settings for standard Users

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, since I've never done this, perhaps some other Linux guru knows how.